# Finding a function f(n) such that T(n) = O(f(n))

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I need some help understanding how to prove that n log n in the equation below is the dominating term. i.e. Given the equation below, find function f(n) such that T(n) = $\theta$(f(n)):

$T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n\;log\;n . i^2}{2^i}$

Intuitively, I would argue that n log n is the dominating term (and hence $\theta(n\;log\;n)$). However I don't understand how I can prove this.

I realize that $\frac{i^2}{2^i}$ is a geometric series. If I can prove that it converges to a constant C, then I can show that n log n dominates. However I don't quite understand how I can go about doing this. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i=\frac1{1-x}$$
Differentiate that with respect to $x$:
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty ix^{i-1}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty(j+1)x^j=\frac1{(1-x)^2}$$
Rearrange it a little, and you can find $\sum i/2^i$.  Differentiate again, rearrange it again, and you can find $\sum i^2/2^i$.  This is a finite number, as you guessed.
$$T(n)=n\log n\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^2}{2^i}=n\log n\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} i^2(\frac12)^i$$

Comment: Thanks! I don't quite understand - could you elaborate? How did you arrive at 1 / 1 - x?

Comment: The first geometric series that people learn is $1+x+x^2+x^3+...=1/(1-x)$

Comment: It is relevant in this case when $x=1/2$.

Comment: I still don't follow. Can you elaborate? I don't see how your answer connects with my problem.